# How to reduce the use of "the" article

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

I am writing a document in geo-related engineering. I realized using LaTeX that I am repeating too much the use of "the" article.

Example:

> Leaflet-sidebar: plugin to add responsive sidebar which is used to include **the** map legend and additional layer controls. Usage API can be accessed in **the** plugin github web page [11]. **The** listing 4.6 shows the implementation of **the** sidebar plugin.

I wonder if it is alright to repeat the article when writing a formal document as this one, otherwise I'd like to know if you have some suggestion to improve the grammatical syntax of my writing.

Comment: Native speakers don't read the word *the* by itself. We read complete noun phrases.  If all your noun phrases are appropriate, you're probably not 'overusing *the*'... But I've no idea what LaTeX is, so I can speak to its context.

Comment: I've never heard any suggestion that using articles too often was a fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Kate Bunting commented, I too have not heard any suggestion to avoid using *the*.

Removing those would only be necessitated by strict word-limit, as in a 140-character tweet, or if it is headlinese.

In the given sentence, I see no reason to cut out some of the *the*. And clarity is more important in such a document than brevity, I assume.

Answer (score -2):

Getting spaces between words is a pain when using LaTeX to write English prose. That difficulty may encourage dropping words not absolutely necessary and thus result in very awkward prose. If you use \text {...}, you can write good prose within the brackets and get the spacing you expect. I have never used LaTeX to write an article so I do not know how it handles multiple lines of prose, paragraphing, pagination, footnotes, endnotes, etc. There probably is at least one good site for help with LaTeX, which does have a fussy syntax, but is wonderful for writing math.

EDIT: I agree that dropping "the" from where normal English usage expects it is not a good idea. So I am not disagreeing with other answers or comments. I just have used LaTeX enough to know why you might be induced to write in a severely abbreviated way. The answer is not to abuse English, but rather to get help with LaTeX.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the down vote?

Comment: Should somebody who has very little experience with  LaTeX really be giving LaTeX advice? LaTeX has very little trouble with word spacing if it's trying to typeset stuff on a normal-sized page. (Would anybody still be using it if it did?) It has real trouble if you're trying to typeset stuff in a very narrow column, and undoubtedly in some other situations, one of which you were probsbly trying to use it for.

Comment: Got it. I did not say that I had little experience with LaTeX. I use it daily. But I get your point that I have no experience using it to write articles.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question. Spacing is not an issue. It's whether to use 'the' for correctness.

Comment: @Mitch Obviously I was trying to figure out why LaTeX gave rise to an issue of the number of uses of "the." If you use LaTeX primarily (or in my case exclusively) to render mathematical text, spaces are ignored unless you take special steps. This encourages omission of words (mathematicians like symbols, not words). As Shor pointed out, my answer may have been way off the mark because I am unfamiliar with using LaTeX to prepare articles. I have left my answer up because I still have no idea what prompted the question, and the OP's experience with LaTeX may also be primarily related to math.